# Asp page not running in firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, asp-classic

I have a classic asp page which is working on IE and safari but not in firefox or chrome.  Have a look at this url

[Check it](http://www.interrig.com.sg/)

My Asp Page code is

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>USER LOGIN</TITLE>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function SetFocus() {
    var field = document.forms("Form1").item("txtUserID");
    field.select();
    field.focus();
}
//-->
</script>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style>
.v8Blue{ font-family:Verdana; font-size:8pt; color:#1E3B51;}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF LEFTMARGIN=0 TOPMARGIN=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0>
<table width="75%" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td height="80">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"> 
      <%

' Check if User has previously rejected by the Server for invalid Log On
If Session("RequestLogOnSuccess_Delphi") = "NO" then
    Response.Write "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>"
    Response.Write "<tr>"
    Response.Write "<td align='center'><font face='Arial, Verdana, Times New Roman' size='2' color='#CC0000'>YOUR LOG ON IS INVALID. PLEASE TRY AGAIN.</font></td>"
    Response.Write "</tr>"
    Response.Write "</table>"
else
    Response.Write "<p>&nbsp;</p>"
End if  

    %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<form method="post" action="../Request_WebProcess/Request_LogOn_Process.asp" name="Form1">
  <table width=23% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align="center" height="119">
    <tr> 
      <td colspan=7> <img src="images/login_01.jpg" width=370 height=58 alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="35" rowspan=4> <img src="images/login_03.jpg" width=35 height=83 alt=""></td>
      <td colspan=2> 
        <div align="center"> 
          <input name="txtUserID" type="text" class="v8blue" id="username" size="15">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="12" rowspan=2> <img src="images/login_05.jpg" width=12 height=27 alt=""></td>
      <td colspan=2> 
        <div align="center"> 
          <input name="txtPassword" type="password" class="v8blue" id="password" size="15">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="64" rowspan=4> <img src="images/login_07.jpg" width=54 height=83 alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td colspan=2> <img src="images/login_08.jpg" width=133 height=4 alt=""></td>
      <td colspan=2> <img src="images/login_09.jpg" width=136 height=4 alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="100" rowspan=2> <img src="images/login_10.jpg" width=100 height=56 alt=""></td>
      <td colspan=3> <a href="#"><img src="images/login_11.jpg" name="Image19" width="82" height="30" border="0" onClick="document.forms('Form1').submit()"></a></td>
      <td width="99" rowspan=2> <img src="images/login_12.jpg" width=99 height=55 alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td colspan=3 height="21"> <img src="images/login_13.jpg" width=82 height=26 alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td colspan=7 height="2"> <img src="images/login_14.jpg" width=370 height=20 alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td colspan=7>&nbsp; </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td width="35"> <img src="images/spacer.gif" width=35 height=1 alt=""></td>
      <td width="100"> <img src="images/spacer.gif" width=100 height=1 alt=""></td>
      <td width="33"> <img src="images/spacer.gif" width=33 height=1 alt=""></td>
      <td width="12"> <img src="images/spacer.gif" width=12 height=1 alt=""></td>
      <td width="38"> <img src="images/spacer.gif" width=37 height=1 alt=""></td>
      <td width="99"> <img src="images/spacer.gif" width=99 height=1 alt=""></td>
      <td width="64"> <img src="images/spacer.gif" width=54 height=1 alt=""></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="70%" border="0" align="center">
    <tr align="center"> 
      <td width="51%" height="12">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="49%" height="12">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center"> 
      <td colspan="2"><img src="../Delphi_Logo.gif" width="397" height="77"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center"> 
      <td colspan="2"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="4"><font face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="4"><font face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif"><font color="#CC9933" size="5"><font size="4" color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">SINGAPORE 
        INTERNET PURCHASE</font></font></font></font></font></font></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="63%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr align="center"> 
      <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="4"><i><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#993333" size="2">(Please 
        log in your user name and password ) </font><font face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" color="#993333"></font></i></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center"> 
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center"> 
      <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><a href="ForgetPassword.asp">CLICK 
        HERE IF YOU FORGET YOUR PASSWORD</a></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center"> 
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="97">
    <tr> 
      <td height="70">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the browser's console? This is the error that Chrome reports:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'forms' of object #<HTMLDocument> is not a function
```

Change this line:

```
var field = document.forms("Form1").item("txtUserID");
```

to be:

```
var field = document.forms["Form1"]["txtUserID"];
// or
var field = document.forms.Form1.txtUserID;
```

Or I would probably do this:

```
var field = document.getElementById("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution

Changed

```
<td colspan=3> <a href="#"><img src="images/login_11.jpg" name="Image19" width="82" height="30" border="0" onClick="document.forms('Form1').submit()"></a></td>
```

To

```
 <td colspan=3> <a href="#"><img src="images/login_11.jpg" name="Image19" width="82" height="30" border="0" onClick="document.forms[0].submit()"></a></td>
```